# Generating projection using graphql file for DGS client

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, netflix-dgs

I'm trying to write a java-graphql client using Netflix DGS.
In the developer [documentation](https://netflix.github.io/dgs/advanced/java-client/), the following sample code is given for generating query using classes generated with DGS codegen.

```
GraphQLQueryRequest graphQLQueryRequest =
                new GraphQLQueryRequest(
                    new TicksGraphQLQuery.Builder()
                        .first(first)
                        .after(after)
                        .build(),
                    new TicksConnectionProjectionRoot()
                        .edges()
                            .node()
                                .date()
                                .route()
                                    .name()
                                    .votes()
                                        .starRating()
                                        .parent()
                                    .grade());
```

Here all the fields to be queried are given in the code itself, using `TicksConnectionProjectionRoot`.

But if I want to query 15-20 fields with many nested types then it will be tiresome. Is there any way to generate the graphql request or a projection like this using a .graphql file containing the grapqhl query and fields needed.

Answer (score 2):

If it is your junit test then I would suggest to use DgsQueryExecutor directly.

```
ExecutionResult result = dgsQueryExecutor.execute(getQuery("/graphql/request/query1.txt"));
    
public static String getQuery(String path) throws IOException {
    InputStream stream = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(path)
    return IOUtils.toString(stream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            
}
```

`query.txt` contains actual graph query string the client sends via http request.

DgsQueryExecutor has various methods to suit most of testing needs.

If calling via http then you can use `MonoGraphQLClient` and pass your query string directly.

```
WebClient webClient = WebClient.create(url);
WebClientGraphQLClient client = MonoGraphQLClient.createWithWebClient(webClient);
//The GraphQLResponse contains data and errors.
Mono<GraphQLResponse> graphQLResponseMono = graphQLClient.reactiveExecuteQuery(query);
```

`query` is string and you can read it from resource.
More about client can be found at https://netflix.github.io/dgs/advanced/java-client/ and https://fullstackcode.dev/2022/02/10/java-graphql-client-using-netflix-dgs-framework/